# Pygame: How to reset background to new position once player dies

Tags: python, pygame

So im making a game in pygame that is a vertical platformer. Right now, I have a background image that scrolls vertically. I also have platforms, enemies, powerups that also scroll, but they are seperate from the background. However, once the player dies, that background image stays where it was when the player died. Basically if the player dies and tries again, the background will be at the same height as it was when the player died, so everything looks weird and out of place. I was wondering if I could reset the background to the player position so everything would align correctly. Any other ideas would also be helpful
Heres my important code. Shoot me a comment if you need any more:

```
#Enemies spawning
for ene in self.enemy_list:
    e = enemy(*ene)
    self.all_enemy.add(e)
    self.all_sprites.add(e)

#Platforms spawning
for plat in self.platform_list:
    p = Platform(*plat)
    self.all_sprites.add(p)
    self.platforms.add(p)

#Power ups spawning
for powerup in self.powerup_list:
    pu = powerUp(*powerup)
    self.all_sprites.add(pu)
    self.powerups.add(pu)
self.run()








# Scrolling Screen
            if self.player.rect.top <= screenLength / 4:
                self.player.pos.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
                background.scroll(0,int(abs(self.player.vel.y)))
                #Enemy Scrolling
                for ene in self.all_enemy:
                    ene.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
                #Platform Scrolling
                for plat in self.platforms:
                    plat.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
                    if plat.rect.top >= screenLength:
                        plat.kill()


                #Projectile scrolling
                for bull in self.bullets:
                    bull.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)
                #Powerup scrolling
                for powerup in self.powerups:
                    powerup.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)

                #End object scrolling
                for End in self.endings:
                    End.rect.y += abs(self.player.vel.y)

     #Dying
        if self.health <= 0:
            self.playing = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a `default_background` which would be the image and wouldn't change, then when you setup the game in `new()`, make background = default_background with `background = default_background.copy()`. So it starts at the default. then scroll `background` and when you need to reset it, just make background = default_background again

Comment: Sorry, but what would default_background be the same as?

Comment: @ArjunSharma ive updated the answer, do you want me to show you in your code?